# Form errors that screen reader can access in angular form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, wai-aria, aria-live

Basically i want the inline form errors to be announced. I have following kind of form in angular 7

```
 <form testForm="ngForm">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" #email="ngModal" 
       aria-labelledby="emailReqError emailPatternError">
    // Error handling part
    <span *ngIf="email.errors?.required" id="emailReqError">
     Please enter Email
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="email.errors?.pattern" id="emailPatternError">
      Please enter valid email address
    </span> 
    <button type="submit" (click)="login(testForm)">Sign In</button>
 </form>
```

Somehow **pattern** inline error is not announced when user typing invalid email address. This error is display in UI when user typing.. same thing i want for the screen reader to announce this error. I also tried **aria-live="assertive"** but it seems not working for the pattern span.
I am using **chromevox screenreader.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Alert_Role) role

```
<form testForm="ngForm">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" #email="ngModal" 
       aria-labelledby="emailReqError emailPatternError">
    // Error handling part
    <span role="alert" *ngIf="email.errors?.required" id="emailReqError">
     Please enter Email
    </span>
    <span role="alert" *ngIf="email.errors?.pattern" 
     id="emailPatternError">
      Please enter valid email address
    </span> 
    <button type="submit" (click)="login(testForm)">Sign In</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried alert & it immediately announce the error but as role is alert  it announces Alert but ideally it is not like alert dialog in UI. Let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: I have suggested  role=alert since it is equivalent to using aria-live=assertive.

Comment: Chen this for some more detailed info:https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA19.html